# Rails has_many update with empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following form code:

```
= form_for @task, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  .form-group
    .col-sm-9.col-sm-offset-3
      = render partial: 'shared/form_errors', locals: { subject: @task }
  .form-group
    label.col-sm-3.control-label for='title' Title
    .col-sm-9
      = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Title'
  .form-group
    label.col-sm-3.control-label for='description' Description
    .col-sm-9
      = f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Description'
  .form-group
    label.col-sm-3.control-label Teams
    .col-sm-9
      ul
        - Team.all.each do |t|
          li
            = check_box_tag "team_ids", t.id, @task.teams.include?(t), name: 'task[team_ids][]'
            = t.name
  .form-group
    .col-sm-9.col-sm-offset-3
      = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

As you can see I can select team for my task through checkboxes. My controller:

```
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update(task_params)
      redirect_to tasks_path, flash: { alert: TASK_UPDATING_MESSAGE }
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, team_ids: [])
    end
```

It works good if I update task with some checked teams; but also I want to have ability to check no teams and update taks with empty array of teams. But in this case tasks_params doesn't have team_ids array, and updating doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't update work? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that when you submit your form with nothing checked, you have `params[:task][:team_ids] = nil`.

You can try something like:

```
def task_params
  params[:task][:team_ids] = [] if params[:task][:team_ids].nil?
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, team_ids: [])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [collection_check_boxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes), just replace the list of teams with:

```
ul
  =  f.collection_check_boxes :team_ids ,Team.all, :id, :name do |b|
    = content_tag :li, raw("#{b.label { b.check_box  } }" + b.object.name)
```

And this will do the trick.

Note: With this Rails add a hidden field, which fix your issue, also you will fix it only with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="task[team_ids][]" value="" autocomplete="off">
```